# Serve two apps with the same internal ports on Docker network using nginx

Tags: docker, nginx

I am serving two React apps (let's call them A and B) using Docker and I'm using NGINX to have a reverse proxy in order too make it easier to access them. All 3 containers are in the same network.

App A is being served on port `3000` and app B is server on port `3001`

Here it is my `default.conf` file:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

   location /app-a {
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_pass http://app-a:3000;
   }

   location /app-b {
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_pass http://app-b:3001;
   }
     
}
```

I can access both apps if I type their ports directly: `my-ip:3000` and `my-ip:3001`

However, I can't access app B (returns 502) if I try to access by NGINX: `my-ip:80/app-b`. Note that `my-ip:80/app-a` works fine.

I noticed that this may be happening due to Docker's networking ports, even though they're exposed as `3000` and `3001` outside, they're both `3000` inside, so I can't access them properly by typing their containers name.

Currently, I'm serving app B by typing my ip directly:

```
location /app-b {
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_pass http://my-ip:3001;
}
```

That's a cheap fix, but does not seem to be a good practice

One solution I tested was building the image for app B using different ports, but this a cheap fix

Any tips?

Comment: Is nginx running in Docker?

Comment: I'm not totally clear what you mean by "inside" and "outside", but connections between containers don't use or require port mappings.  If both Node processes are listening on port 3000, then you should use `proxy_pass http://app-b:3000`.

Comment: @larsks yes
@DavidMaze by "inside" and "outside" I am talking about the mapping you do when creating a container (`-p "outside":"inside"`). App B was created using `-p 3001:3000`, while A was `3000:3000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to use two simple Python serves in lieu of your React apps. Suppose that your project looks like this:

```
├── app-a
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── index.html
├── app-b
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── index.html
├── default.conf
└── docker-compose.yml
```

The contents of `app-a/` and `app-b/` would be replaced with your React applications.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  app-a:
    container_name: app-a
    build:
      context: app-a
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

  app-b:
    container_name: app-b
    build:
      context: app-b
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - app-a
      - app-b
    volumes:
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

`default.conf`

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;

   location /app-a {
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_pass http://app-a:3000;
   }

   location /app-b {
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_pass http://app-b:3000;
   }
}
```

To build and launch the Docker Compose stack:

```
docker-compose build && docker-compose up
```

You should now be able to access the two apps at http://127.0.0.1/app-a and http://127.0.0.1/app-b.

[image]